# Why is this jquery post request not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm learning AJAX right now, using jQuery.
When I try to make this registration system it doesn't work:

```
$('#submitr').click(function () {
    var username = $('#usernamefieldr').val();
    var password = $('#passwordfieldr').val();
    var email = $('#emailfieldr').val();
    alert("ERROR");
    $.post("test.php", {
        input: "register",
        name: username,
        pass: password,
        mail: email
    }, function (data) {
        $("#test").html(data);
        alert(data);
    }).error(function () {
        alert("ERROR");
    });
});
```

but this function works:

```
$.post("test.php", {input: "Ajax is working!"}, function(data){
    $("#test").html(data);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is test.php is throwing an error.

Comment: Have you looked at your browsers traffic inspector to validate what's send/received?

Comment: for starters on line 5 you're always alert('ERROR') is that a mstake ?

Answer (score 1):

Your bottom example works:

```
$.post("test.php", {input: "Ajax is working!"}, function(data){
    $("#test").html(data);
});
```

But your top doesn't.  Put in dummy data you know will validate properly in test.php and run it:

```
$.post("test.php", {input: "register", name: "dummyName", pass: "dummyPass", mail: "test@test.com"}, function(data){
    $("#test").html(data);
    alert(data);
});
```

If it doesn't work and you know you've written that line of JQuery correctly, you likely have a problem in test.php.   If it does, then add your variables one at a time:

```
$('#submitr').click(function(){

  var username=$('#usernamefieldr').val();

  $.post("test.php", {input: "register", name: username, pass: "dummyPass", mail: "test@test.com"}, function(data){
     $("#test").html(data);
     alert(data);
  });
```

});

Does it work? If so, add the next var...and so on.  When it breaks you know where the issue is then.

You could also try:

```
$('#submitr').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       url:'test.php'
       type: 'post'
       data: $('#form').serialize();
    }).done(function(data){
       $('#test').html(data);
       alert(data);
    }).fail(function(){
       alert('Oh No!');
    });
});
```

And then just pull the data you need from the $_POST in test.php:

```
<?php

   $name  = $_POST['name'];
   $pass  = $_POST['pass'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];

   // Do stuff here

?>
```